# голос за закрытие засчитался, а проверка — нет

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

вчера, обрабатывая очередь проверок за закрытие, я отметил вариант «закрыть» для вопроса «[Как отсортировать массив по полю?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/602934/178576)» (ссылку на проверку я, к сожалению, забыл сохранить).

голос за закрытие был последним из ограничения в 24 ежесуточных, он был благополучно принят, а сама проверка **не засчиталась**: движок ответил мне сообщением, что «достигнут лимит голосований» (точный текст я, к сожалению, забыл сохранить, но он явно отличался от стандартного сообщения о достижении ежесуточного ограничения на двадцать проверок в очереди). это не могло относиться к проверкам в данной очереди — их к тому моменту было ровно 19 из двадцати возможных, да и если бы этот лимит был достигнут, то двадцать первую проверку мне бы движок не предоставил.

получается, что это был либо случайный сбой, либо проявление пока не выявленной ошибки в очереди проверок.

Comment: Что-то странное там. До меня было отдано 3 голоса за один вариант дубликата и 1 за второй. Значит, мой был пятым. Однако, в проверке я вижу только один голос — свой. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/128402

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но ведь голоса за закрытие могут быть не только из очереди.

Comment: @Qwertiy, как минимум, мой голос за закрытие точно был отдан в очереди, нажатием кнопки «закрыть».

Comment: @NickVolynkin только один Ваш голос может быть из-за того, что модераторский? Хотя вроде обычно, те кто раньше голосовал, тоже отображаются. Надо переводить на английский и ждать реакции :) В соответствии с новой политикой постинга багов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а с двумя новыми проверками (ссылки в ответе) ничего странного нет?

Answer (score 7):

ура! ситуация стала яснее: удалось воспроизвести тот же сбой.

сегодня повторились ровно те же обстоятельства:

1. из лимита голосов за закрытие (`24`) остался **один** голос
2. из лимита проверок в очереди на закрытие (`20`) осталась **одна** проверка

мои действия:

1. нажимаю кнопку «закрыть» в [этой проверке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/129041)
2. выбираю причину
3. нажимаю кнопку «голосовать за закрытие»

результат действий:

1. получаю сообщение: «На сегодня у вас больше не осталось голосов за закрытие, возвращайтесь через 12 часов.» ([tx:3612 You have no more close votes today; come back $when$.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265484))
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. счётчик оставшихся голосов за закрытие устанавливается в значение `0`
3. количество сделанных проверок остаётся в значении `19`

ожидаемый результат:

1. получить сообщение о совершении максимального количества проверок в очереди
2. количество сделанных проверок должно быть установлено в значение `20`

(на данный момент на странице вопроса написано, что за его закрытие есть четыре голоса).

---

**и ещё раз** воспроизвёл ровно ту же ситуацию: остался один голос за закрытие и одна проверка в очереди.

[голосую за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/129838) и:

- получаю сообщение «На сегодня у вас больше не осталось голосов за закрытие, возвращайтесь через 16 минут»
- при этом голос за закрытие засчитывается
- а проверка в очереди — **нет**.

(на данный момент на странице вопроса написано, что за его закрытие есть два голоса).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по-моему, это уже явно система и готовый баг-репорт (перевод, увы, не потяну).

Comment: чтоб никто не подумал, что я «махаю банхаммером налево и направо», уточню, что пользуюсь этой придумкой: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4155/178576